# Why is Unity UI Canvas Button not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, inspector

[This is the hierarchy for the app I'am trying to build. You can see that I have the button for the **Main UI**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9tkE.png)

[This is how the inspector of the **Main UI** looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC08F.png)

[This is how the **UI Canvas** inspector looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNTeO.png)

[This is the inspector the **Interaction Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOeUA.png)

[This is my EventSystem. It looks like this because I am using the new InputSystem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D54CG.png)

I want the **Main UI Button** to load the next UI which is the **Select Model UI** but when after building it to my device, nothing happens when I click on the button.
I need help understanding what is the issue.

Comment: You said you had problems when you were building it to your device. Was it working normally when you were testin in the editor?

Comment: In editor in only loads the first UI which is the Startup UI

Comment: check if there is a collider blocking the button, also check if the camera has a graphics raycaster component (I think it's called like this) and let me know if you still have the problem

Comment: What do you mean by collider? Besides the detect planes there is nothing else on the screen when the UI with the button starts up. The camera does not have a graphics Raycaster, should I add it?

Comment: Try adding the physics Raycaster component to the camera and see if it works

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am using universal render pipeline, could it have something to do with that?